# How many sprockets can I fit on a crank?

Tags: chainring, hypothetical, customization

So, I have a pair of ambidextrous shifters on my bike. In other words, both shifters are ten-speed so that you can change the "handedness" of your handlebar if you want. This got me thinking, they could also be used for a 10x10 drivetrain.

So, how many speed chainring is achievable with reasonably off-the-shelf components, and what (if anything) would stop me from building a 100-speed bike, and at what point?

Comment: You mean 'how many 'chain-ring sprockets can be fitted on a crank'?

Comment: Oh, no, is this another round of Jon like gearing questions.

Comment: I'm really curious to find out what 'a pair of ambidextrous shifters' are. Do you have a link to a product web page?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus [This is the product I'm talking about](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/road/shifting---braking/shift-levers0/sl-4700.html), basically it's just a pair of ten speed shifters with different handedness.

Comment: ...Ambidextrous in this context meaning the left-hand shifter could also serve as the right-hand one and vice versa.

Comment: Left shifter is not a front derailleur shifter

Comment: Where on that linked page does it say they are ambidexterous?  You have a left hand shifter with two positions, and a right hand shifter with 10 positions.  Swapping sides means they are upside down, and may not fit around your brake levers.

Comment: @Criggie the way the physical product in my possession has ten positions for the front derailleur says they're ambidextrous. Also, please make that last comment an answer.

Comment: @haem OK thank you - can you please add a photo of your shifter to the question?  I've never seen one that could be classed as ambidexterous.

Comment: @Criggie I suspect the choice of the word "ambidextrous" was bad. The shifters really look like one left-handed and one right-handed shifter.

Comment: Setting aside my skepticism about the shifters, one of the limiting factors is going to be the rear derailleur's capacity for chain wrap. Unless you have chainrings that are very close in size, most (all?) derailleurs will be unable to wrap up that much chain and maintain chain tension. Lengthening the derailleur cage brings its own problems. Another problem could be cross-chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front chainrings are limited to 3, practically by the width.

Remember the chain is under tension as it arrives onto the chainring, whereas its under tension when leaving the rear cassette. So its much more sensitive to arrival angles on the front.

I've ridden a bike with quad chainring, and it was very bad at front shifting, to the point friction shift was required with manual trimming as you moved across the cassette.

[image: Own work]

Comment: The rings on that setup appear to lack "ramps", and hence friction shifting would be the norm.

Comment: @DanielRHicks yes - cross-chaining was very noticeably bad.  Running on big/small or small/big was fine but totherwise the chainline was too angled at the first contact point with the chainrings.  Looks like it was used in the middle rings most of its life for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

4 chainrings seems to be the feasible limit:

http://abundantadventures.com/quads.html

However if you add an internal planetary gear setup, A 100 speed might be possible if not practical. Here's a 63 speed bike.

https://sheldonbrown.com/org/otb.html

There are internally geared 2speed front axles.

https://www.alphabent.com/internally-geared-cranksets

So in theory 8x is possible on the front, 12 on the back gets you close to 100. You could go 14 in the back with a Rolhoff hub and get over 100.

I suspect such a bike would self-destruct in a very few miles though. Internal gear systems aren't engineered for the kind of forces that gearing could generate.